# What determines the order of an element in the group of units $U(n)$?

Tags: group-theory

Consider the group of units $U(n)$.

For example, if $n=10$ then $|U(10)| = 4$ and $|1|=1, |9|=2$ and $|3|=|7|=4$.

When I tried to determine the orders of the elements at first I made the mistake to think that because $3,7$ and $9$ are coprime to $10$ they should have order $|U(10)| = 4$. That's not the case.

Then I thought numbers that are coprime to all other group members have maximal order $|U(n)|$. That's not the case either!

To see this let's look at another example:

If $n=12$ then $|1|=1, |5|=|7|=|11|=2$.

I'm trying to work out a way of determining the order of an element in $U(n)$.

> Is there a way to determine the order of an element in $U(n)$?

Comment: Not always the group of units $U(n)$ is cyclic (has a generator)

Comment: You are determing the order of elements in your examples. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I can do for you. Let's take $U(24) = \{1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23 \}$ for example.
The mapping $f:U_{24} \to U_8 \times U_3$ defined by 
$n \mapsto (n, n)$ is a multiplicative-group isomorphism.

Just to support that claim, we find that

\begin{array}{rr}
   f(1)=(1,1) & f(17)=(1,2)\\
  f(19)=(3,1) & f(11)=(3,2)\\
  f(13)=(5,1) &  f(5)=(5,2)\\
   f(7)=(7,1) & f(23)=(7,2)\\
\end{array}

So, for example, the order of $11$ in $U_{24}$ is equal to the order of 
$(3,2)$ in $U_8 \times U_3$.

Since $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, the order of 
$11$ in $U_{24}$ must be equal to $\text{LCM}(2,2) = 2$.

We see that $11^2 \equiv 121 \equiv 1 \pmod{24}$.

Comment: That's fine but if you say best *you* can do does it mean that there may be other results out there that you don't know?

Comment: @astudent :  And how could I answer that question with a yes or a no? I don't think that you can do better than finding the order of an element in a group of prime-power order.

Comment: Haha, good point.